# Voice recognition offline mode for windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, offline, voice-recognition

I am creating a app in **windows 8 for desktop and tablets** using C# and XAML.

I would like to know if there are any controls available to recognize voice in **offline mode**, I know there are some controls like

**[Bing Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx)**

for voice recognition which connects to a web service for data analysis (I used it and it works great), but my requirement is the user should be able to work with my app even when there is no wi-fi or internet connectivity.

I tried searching for some offline controls but could find some only for android. any suggestions or help will be helpful.